# Problem in understanding this notation $ \Phi: \mathcal{P}(X)\rightarrow \lbrace0,1\rbrace^{X}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let X be an not-empty set. The function 
$$ \Phi: \mathcal{P}(X)\rightarrow \lbrace0,1\rbrace^{X}, A\longmapsto \chi_{A} $$

Show that $Φ$ is bijection and give the reverse function in explicit form. I know that $\lbrace0,1\rbrace^{X}$ means all functions $X\rightarrow \lbrace0,1\rbrace$. But how is that possible that $Φ$ is an bijection? I thank that $Φ$ isn't a injection, because there are more than one function that hits 1 or 0.

Comment: $\Phi$ is a function whose domain is the set of subsets of $X$ and whose range is the set of functions on $X$.. When $A$ is a subset of $X$, $\Phi(A)$ is a particular function on $X$ that takes on $0$ and $1$ as values. Of course different functions on $X$ take on those values at different places in $X$.

Answer (score 2):

You can think that each function in $\{0,1\}^X$ represent a subset of $X$ as follows:

Given $f\in \{0,1\}^X$, let $A_f=\{x\in X: f(x)=1\}$. Then $f=\chi_{A}$ and the function $\Psi: \{0,1\}^X \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$, given by $\Psi(f) = A_f$, is the inverse of $\Phi$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\chi_{A} (x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x\in A$;}\\
0 & \text{if $x\in X\setminus A$.}
\end{cases}
$$
Suppose $\Phi(A)=\chi_{A}=\chi_{B}=\Phi(B)$ for some $A, B\subseteq X$. Then $\chi_{A}(x)=\chi_{B}(x)$ for all $x\in X$. In particular $$A=\chi_{A} ^{-1}(1)=\chi_{A} ^{-1}(B)=B$$
so the map is injective.